Bandgap calculations of a supercell using castep?
I am calculating the bandgap of the bismuth tungstate using castep in Materials Studio. The results are fairly accurate using the DFT+U approach.
However, there's no bandgap when I build a supercell from the initial structure (2x1x1).
I am using an identical ZB path for both calculations.
Help is appreciated.
Jawwad

Could you post your input files for both cases? It's difficult to know what the problem might be without a bit more detail.

Do you get the sort of bandgap you are expecting with a primitive unit cell?
